# integrable function in Lebesgue sense

Tags: integration

How we prove that $\displaystyle{f : x \mapsto \frac{x}{e^{x}-1}}$
is Lebesgue integrable in $\mathbb{R}_{+}$?

Answer (score 1):

Use Taylor series to see that $e^x-1 \geq x$ and $e^x-1 \geq x^3/6$, for $x \geq 0$. So

$$0 \leq \frac{x}{e^x-1} \leq \frac{x}{\max \{ x,x^3/6 \}} = \min \left \{ 1,\frac{6}{x^2} \right \}.$$

Can you work from here?

Another approach, which actually gives a way to calculate the integral:

$$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\frac{x e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}=x e^{-x} \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nx}.$$

Hence

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{e^x-1} dx = \int_0^\infty x e^{-x} \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nx} dx.$$

Then you can interchange summation and integration using monotone convergence. This leaves you to compute

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty x e^{-(n+1)x} dx.$$

Using integration by parts, you get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}.$$

One shows that this series converges in calc II; using Fourier series methods one can show that the value is $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: there is another way to prove it?

Comment: @salma Short of actually calculating the integral, any proof is going to find some sort of dominating function like I did. There might be a way without Taylor series, though.

Comment: @salma I've written another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another dominating function which does not use Taylor series. Consider $e^x/2$. At $x=\ln(2)$, $e^x/2=e^x-1$. This is the only point where these two functions are equal. At $x=\ln(4)$, $e^x/2<e^x-1$, so by continuity, we know that $e^x/2<e^x-1$ for all $x>ln(2)$. Thus, $$\int_{\ln(2)}^\infty\frac{x}{e^x-1}dx\leq\int_{\ln(2)}^\infty2xe^{-x}dx=1+\ln(2).$$
Now we just have to show that 
$$\int_0^{\ln(2)}\frac{x}{e^x-1}dx<\infty.$$
We know that the integrand is continuous on $(0,\ln(2)]$. If we we can show
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{e^x-1}<\infty,$$
then the integrand is bounded on a set of finite measure. Calculating the limit is simple if we use L'Hopital's rule:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{e^x}=0.$$
Thus,
$$\int_0^{\ln(2)}\frac{x}{e^x-1}dx<\infty,$$
so
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^x-1}dx=\int_0^{\ln(2)}\frac{x}{e^x-1}dx+\int_{\ln(2)}^\infty2xe^{-x}dx=<\infty.$$

If you are curious, the actual value of the integral is $\pi^2/6$.

Comment: You have some errors that ultimately cancel out: for $x>\ln(2)$ you have $e^x/2<e^x-1$, from which it follows that $\frac{1}{e^x/2}>\frac{1}{e^x-1}$.